# Worklight - Enable Translation

Tags: translation, ibm-mobilefirst

From the [Worklight tutorial - 05_05_Enabling_translation.pdf](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/05_05_Enabling_translation.pdf) ([Sample app](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/EnablingTranslationProject.zip)), we can
1. Define the translated message in messages.js 
2. Reference the message in HTML as the ID of an HTML element with `class="translate"` or as a JavaScript object property `Messages.<ID>`. 
3. Implement a languageChanged function to set a new value of `Messages.<ID>` and update the content to selected language.

In the example - languageChanged(lang) function:
`$("#sampleText").html(Messages.sampleText);`
`$("#headerText").html(Messages.headerText);`
`$("#actionsLabel").html(Messages.actionsLabel);`
is used to update the content to selected language. 

From my understanding, it is required to write the above line of codes to update the content to selected language. 
Is there a better way to update the content if there are lots of elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily iterate over all elements by using jQuery selectors and update text, e.g. something like

```
$(".translate").each(function(index, element){
  element = $(element);
  var elementId = element.attr("id");
  element.text(Messages[elementId]);
});
```